# Entity Framework Core: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.1

I am using Sql Server on Linux with EC Core (2.1.0-preview1-final)

I am trying to update some data coming from a web Api service (PUT) request.  The data (ticket) is passed correctly and gets deserialised into an object (ticket).

When I try to update, I use the following code:

```
public Ticket UpdateTicket(Ticket ticket)
        {
            using (var ctx = new SupportTicketContext(_connectionString))
            {
                ctx.Entry(ticket).State = EntityState.Modified;
                ctx.SaveChanges(); // <== **BLOWS UP HERE**
                var result = ctx.Tickets
                    .First(t => t.TicketId == ticket.TicketId);
                return result;

            }
        }
```

The code throws the following error:

**Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data 
may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded**

- I am able to Insert and fetch from the database, no problem.
- If I restart Visual Studio, the error occurs usually on the second time I try to update ANY ticket (i.e. any other ticketId - it seems to be on the second and subsequent requests).
- The updates are unpredictably successful!  Sometimes I can update another ticket and it goes through (even on the 3rd or susequent request)
- I have tried a number of modifications to the code, including

  ctx.Attach(ticket);

but this does not help.

How do I get it to update the database successfully?
Any ideas on how to debug this?  Logging seems to be difficult to set up.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my case i used an extension for bulk delete, that causing the error.

Answer (score 36):

There were two errors. First, I tried to call the Update() method without specifying a DbSet:

```
_applicationDbContext.Update(user);
```

Correct way:

```
_applicationDbContext.Users.Update(user);
```

The second error was trying to update a model that without first pulling it from the database:

```
    public bool UpdateUser(IdentityUser model)
    {
        _applicationDbContext.Users.Update(model);
        _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

Nope.

I first needed to retrieve it from the database, then update it:

```
    public bool UpdateUser(IdentityUser model)
    {
        var user = _applicationDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == model.Id);

        user.PhoneNumberConfirmed = model.PhoneNumberConfirmed;

        _applicationDbContext.Users.Update(user);
        _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, make sure you pull first.  This one has caught me too many times.

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities if Update() is causing issues for you. For me I read Update is basically AddOrUpdate but it has some exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

Had such problem too, but the reason was a trigger I was using.

Changed the trigger type from "INSTEAD OF INSERT" to "AFTER INSERT" and instead of modifying and inserting the data I was allowing my command to insert the data to the table and then updated it using the trigger.